# Pasar un string obtenido con javascript a php

Tags: php, javascript, java

Tengo un Sketch de processing embebido en un html, este atraves de una peticion de javascript, me entrega un string `"serie=11&temp=22"`, necesito enviar eso a un archivo php dentro del mismo directorio.

No logro que envie nada.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
     <title>Hello Web - Accessing JavaScript from Processing</title>
     <script src="processing.js"></script>
     <script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php require 'prueba.php';?>
     <div id="msg">
     </div>
     <canvas data-processing-sources="sketch_180814b.pde"></canvas>
     <script type="application/javascript">
         var jsString = "Hello from JavaScript!";
         var yeah = "serie=11&temp=22";
         var printMessage = function (msg)
         {
             document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Message: " + msg;
         }

     </script>

     <script type="application/javascript">

        var parametros = msg;
        $.ajax({
                data:   parametros, //datos que se envian a traves de ajax
                url:   'prueba.php', //archivo que recibe la peticion
                type:  'get', //método de envio
                beforeSend: function () {
                        $("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
                },
                success:  function (response) { //una vez que el archivo recibe el request lo procesa y lo devuelve
                        $("#resultado").html(response);
                }
        });
      }
     </script>
   </body>
   </html>




<?php

$enlace = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");   
mysqli_select_db($enlace,"frigorifico");          
mysqli_query($enlace,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$serie = $_GET ['serie'];
$temperatura = $_GET ['temp'];

mysqli_query($enlace, "INSERT INTO `datos` (`id`, `fecha`, `serie`, 
`temperatura`) VALUES (NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$serie', '$temperatura');" 
);

mysqli_close($enlace);

echo "datos ingresados correctamente";

?>
```

Comment: puedes añadir el codigo del archivo "prueba.php"? puede ser que haya un fallo en ese archivo. Te sugiero que añadas el ".error:function(){} en tu llamada ajax para ver si hay algun error en la llamada.

Comment: listo, mas abajo agregue el codigo php, de hecho con una simple form get, lo hago funcionar pero no logro hacerlo de esta manera

Comment: si te fijas desde el ajax estas mandando : parametros.....de la misma forma debes recibir en el php

Comment: te sugiero que hagas algo asi y veas como recibes los parametros en php: $data_recibida = $_GET ['parametros']; .....var_dump($data_recibida);

Comment: no deberías enviar `yeah` en lugar de `msg` que no está definido ?

Comment: @Emeeus ya lo hice de hecho, y no funciona u.u

Comment: Tu código es algo extraño. Aquí `var parametros = msg;` pides que `parametros` adquiera el valor de `msg` (no sé para qué ni por qué), pues podrías haber hecho esto: `data:   msg,`  ... aunque de todos modos, no veo en qué parte `msg` adquiere el valor de `yeah`, el cual contiene los datos que quieres enviar en realidad. Tampoco entiendo por qué tienes dos `script`  ¿? . Si pones todo en un solo `script` y pones esto así: `data:   yeah,` debería funcionar. No hay por qué marear tanto los datos.